# Unexpected token: closing div tag

Tags: php, html

I have the following code. When I run it, I get an error message in the console that there is an unexpected token - the closing div tag. I'm unsure why. When the if statement returns false, there is no issue.

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <br><br>
    <h2 class="mb-4 text-white"><? echo $recipe ?></h2>
    <h3> <?echo $description ?> </h3> <br>
    <h3 class="mb-4 text-white"><? echo 'Duration: '. $duration ?></h3>
    <?php
    $query800 = $db->prepare("select * from user_cookbook where userID=:userID");
    $dbParams8 = array('userID'=>$thisUser);
    $query800->execute($dbParams8);
    while ($dbRow8 = $query800->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $recipeIDarray[]=$dbRow8['recipeID'];
    }

    if (in_array($recipeID, $recipeIDarray)){
        echo '<button class="btn btn-light btn-xl sr-button" onclick="window.location.href="/editDisplay.php?id='. $recipeID . '">Edit</button>';
    }

    ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: There's no closing div tag for `<div class="container text-center">`

Comment: Assuming the `while` doesn't start/end any unpaired tags, it looks like you're missing a `</div>` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo '<button class="btn btn-light btn-xl sr-button" onclick="window.location.href="/editDisplay.php?id='. $recipeID . '">Edit</button>';
```

Looking here:

```
onclick="window.location.href="/editDisplay.php?id='. $recipeID . '"
```

You don't have a closing " for the onclick property, only for window.location.href. That could be the problem, because typically it will pick up the ending div as the quotes aren't closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have one closing div-tag short. It took me 2 seconds to find out by pasting your code in Notepad++ and clicking each div to see if it has a closing pair. Just a heads up so you know how to trouble-shoot html tags :)